# fedora 24 - kate and texmaker appear zoomed

Tags: fedora, xfce, vlc, qt, kate

I just installed `texmaker` and `kate` in my fedora 24 system. The problem is that they appear "zoomed in"  and they cannot function properly as the following picture shows

[image]

However, I have a clue on what might be the issue. When I installed `VLC`, the video was appearing on the left bottom corner of the interface, so I added these lines to my `.bashrc` file

```
# VLC - Full screen 
QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=0.5
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS
```

so I think that this is what causes `kate` and `texmaker` to appear zoomed in.

Any idea on how to fix this but having `vlc` showing the videos properly?

*UPDATE*

I changed my `bashrc` entry to

```
# VLC - Full screen 
alias vlc='QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=0.5 vlc'
```

I also installed `qtcurve` and now the behavior is better but still strange :

`TexMakeR` and `Kate` work properly only when opening a file using `right click -> Open`. Rather oddly, double clicking on a file or opening the programs (either on `terminal` or in `Applications->Accessories`) results in the same strange behavior (i.e. program appears "zoomed in").

Comment: I had similar problem with VLC in previous Fedora versions, but Fedora 25 works fine. So I would recommend you to upgrade to Fedora 25. Also downgrade of VLC might help temporarily.

Comment: @Jakuje Thank you very much for your comment. At the moment I don't want to upgrade to fedora 25 (It's my business laptop and it has to have fedora 24) and downgrading `vlc` didn't work...

Comment: Did you try to comment these lines in your .bashrc, resource it (or restart) and try again? Your problem is basically Qt Libraries Look&Feel over GTK (XFCE to be specific) so maybe you can try qtcurve (is in fedora repos: dnf install qtcurve) and/or try to configure your Qt behavior with qtconfig (qt3 and qt4) or qt5ct (Qt5 Config Tool).

Comment: @X3MBoy : Thank you very much for your comment. Please see my updated question.

Comment: For your update, you should check the command on the .desktop file
Menú entries are just "launchers", these are text files with .desktop extensions that contains a command to execute something (normally applications).

If you link wour file with the option "Open with", you can customize the start of the program, but I don't what is the difference between xdg-open (double-click a file) or running the command. IMHO you should test running the application from terminal unsetting the QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS variable first

> unset QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS; kate

Comment: There is a lot of things you should know/check to understand your problem. One of them is XDG Concept (XDG stands for X Desktop Group), and check all the tools and options. Then, understand how "launchers" works, parameters and options. And then, understand QT/KDE Environment Variables that set the behavior of its apps under differents DEs. There are a lot of things that can be done with speciallized apps like qtcurve, systemsettings or qtconfig, but if you understand the things I mention before, your life will be better ;)

Comment: Is this solved now?